# Required form field only if any another form field is filled

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 8 and I would like the form fields of my form group only be required when any other field of the same form group is filled, is there any simple way to do that or do I need to create a custom function to verify if the other form fields were filled?

```
    const CredentialsXYZ: CredentialsXYZ= {
        token: [res.token, [Validators.required]],
        user: [res.user, [Validators.required]],
        password: [res.password, [Validators.required]]
    };
```

Comment: You could create a custom validator. https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-custom-validator/

Comment: What kind of form do you have? If it's a simple template form then you can just do `[required]="this.formGroup.value.dependency_input"` on the input. As in, make the value of input #1 being true (not an empty string) the condition for input #2 being required.

Comment: I'm using angular forms, I will put the piece of code, I would like to avoid creating a custom validator because there are a couple of forms that I need to do the same

Comment: @Nestorzin A custom validator isn't limited to just one form.

Answer (score 3):

Since Angular 13, you can add validators dynamically, like this:

```js
this.formName.controls.controlName.setValidators(Validator.required);
```

or, if the control had any validator before -

```js
this.formName.controls.controlName.addValidators(Validator.required);
```

You can do it by subscribing to `valueChanges` of the control you depend on. For example:

```
const userField = form.controls.user
const passwordField = form.controls.user

userField.valueChanges.subscribe(user => {
  if (user) {
    passwordField.setValidators(Validators.required)
  } else {
    passwordField.clearValidators()
  }

  // Remember to call this for the new validation to take place immediately
  passwordField.updateValueAndValidity()
})
```